# Using strcmp with Index of Array

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I am trying to do coping string to string but

1. Compiler gives Cannot convert Char to constant char for 15,18 Lines;
2. Compiler gives Cannot convert Char to Char For 19,20 Lines;
   Couldn't find what is wrong with this?

   ```
   int main () 
   { 
       int i=0; 
       int j=0;
       int space = 0; 

       char cmp[50]; 
       char *p[50][100];

       for (i=0;i<space;i++) { 
           for ( j = i + 1;j <=space; j++ ) { 
               if( (strcmp(p[i],p[j])=0)) //15 {  
                   strcpy (cmp,p[i]); //18
                   strcpy (p[i],p[j] ); //19
                   strcpy(p[j], cmp); //20
               } 
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: That's certainly a fancy `i` you have in your title...

Comment: BTW I included string library!

Comment: Among other things, inside if `==` instead of `=`

Comment: Please note that `strcpy()` relies on a null terminator to stop the copy. Maybe using `strncpy()` is a better idea.

Comment: Have you included the proper header for `strcmp()` and `strcpy()`? `#include <string.h>`

Comment: among other things ... //15 {  should be { // 15

Comment: `p[I]` is an array of `char*`, but these functions want a single `char*`.  Did you mean to declare `p` as a 2d array of `char*` or as a 1d array of 100 element `char` buffers?  If the latter, just drop the `*` from the type.

Comment: You probably meant `char p[100][50]` so `p[I]` is the same type as `cmp`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code, but let me tell you this code swaps same strings if value of space is some positive number.

```
int main () 
{

    int i=0; 
    int j=0;
    int space = 0; //I hope you initialized the value of space to a different number.

    char cmp[50]; 
    char p[50][100];// do not use *p[50][100]

    for (i=0;i<space;i++) { 
        for ( j = i + 1;j <=space; j++ ) { 
            if( (strcmp(p[i],p[j])==0))  {  //use == for comparison.
                strcpy (cmp,p[i]); 
                strcpy (p[i],p[j] ); 
                strcpy(p[j], cmp); 
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So many problems.....

```
for (i=0;i<space;i++) {
```

What do you think the value of `space` is?
if `space` is zero, how many times do you think this loop will run?
How many times do you *want* it to run?

Comment: I want to control end of size of array so should i assign space=50